# Rails Master Key on GitHub Actions causes ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github

Anyone have experience with using `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` env with GH Actions?
Recently switched to Rails 7 from 6. Using the credentials.yml.enc to store the ActiveRecord encryption stuff. Have set `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` locally and it works fine. Have confirmed I can encode/decode stuff fine. However when pushing to GH and using our CI (running tests etc.) I come across this error:

```
ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage
Caused by:
OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError:
```

I have added the ENV to the GH Action but still no dice:

```
RAILS_MASTER_KEY=${{ secrets.RAILS_MASTER_KEY }}
```

Then I set the secret in the repo as well, it seems it is not reading it correctly?

Comment: Did you add it as a secret? As in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69242971/6309) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65310519/6309).

Comment: @VonC Added RAILS_MASTER_KEY: ${{ secrets.RAILS_MASTER_KEY }} to GH CI env

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix I found for this was adding the following to `test.rb` inside `config/environments`

```rb
  config.active_record.encryption.primary_key = "test"
  config.active_record.encryption.deterministic_key = "test"
  config.active_record.encryption.key_derivation_salt = "test"
```